# Can you explain this phrase to me?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Source](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/sunday-times/deep-focus/Love-Shakespeare-aur-Dhoka/articleshow/51859013.cms)

> Yes, it's in English. Yes, we associate it with school plays, school textbooks and, most harrowingly, **with folks quoting lines from Shakespeare with the express purpose of telling us that they 'know their Shakespeare'**.

Isn't it weird-**we associate it with folks quoting lines from Shakespeare..?**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is.  Could you clarify what you're trying to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source link, we know that the author is discussing the line "To be, or not to be" from Shakespeare's Hamlet.  We can simplify this complex sentence by breaking it up, like so:

> Yes, [the following are true].
>
> "To be, or not to be" is in English.
>
> Shakespeare is often taught in school.
>
> Adults who want to prove they know Shakespeare by quoting it are harrowing.

For context, the author is saying that the above are reasons to dislike or dismiss Shakespeare, but goes on to explain there are still reasons to like it.

I believe you may be asking why quoting Shakespeare is "harrowing".

Fans of Shakespeare (just like fans of anything else) enjoy quoting their favorite scenes.  Between fans, recognizing quotes is a way to identify other fans and show how much one knows about the subject.  However, because Shakespeare in particular is considered culturally important, failing to recognize those quotes feels like failing a test.  If we were taught Shakespeare in school, shouldn't we recognize it now?

This anxiety is often used in fiction to help establish which character is more educated and intelligent.  For instance, in this scene from Star Trek VI (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsCVuO1yeJc) someone makes a toast quoting Shakespeare and gets blank looks from everyone at the table.  Then the genius, Spock, correctly identifies the quote.  This is exactly the sort of "harrowing" experience that the author is discussing - the Chancellor's toast proves he "knows his Shakespeare" and simultaneously embarrasses almost everyone else because they don't.

Comment: It would be better to wait until OP has clarified exactly what he *is* asking about, before launching into what might simply be an irrelevant digression.

Comment: I know, but I really wanted to talk about Star Trek.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem weird to me. It sounds like a quotation from an light opinion or humorous column in a newspaper (Look at David Mitchell in the Observer for examples of what I mean). There's a somewhat over-stated tone of exasperation, slightly tongue-in-cheek.

They are perhaps referring someone dropping a little Shakespeare into the conversation, possibly in a slightly condescending way:

> Once more onto the beach dear friends, as Shakespeare didn't say.

or

> I think you'll find that Shakespeare said "all that glisters is not gold"

the subtext being that the person is claiming superior knowledge of the bard.